# Do permanents reenter the battlefield tapped with Brago, King Eternal?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Let's say I have [Brago, King Eternal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBrago%2c%20King%20Eternal%5d), and a tapped artifact on the field, and I deal combat damage to the enemy player. Brago's ability reads:

> Whenever Brago, King Eternal deals combat damage to a player, exile any number of target nonland permanents you control, then return those cards to the battlefield under their owner's control.

So, using Brago's Ability, I exile and return the artifact I control. Would it still be tapped, or would it return untapped?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Permanents changing zones have no memory of their previous state (meaning tapped or untapped):

> **400.7.** An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. [...]

Due to Brago's ability not invoking any additional state changes to the blinked cards, they will enter the battlefield as they normally would. This means that a [Sol Ring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSol%20Ring%5d) will enter the battlefield untapped, while a [Worn Powerstone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWorn%20Powerstone%5d) would enter the battlefield tapped.

Note that other cards, such as [Eldrazi Displacer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEldrazi%20Displacer%5d), *do* set the state of the card re-entering the battlefield, so those cards will always enter the battlefield tapped.